# How to use UDFs in New BigQuery UI(BETA)? I didnt find anywhere in UI

Tags: google-bigquery

How to use `UDFs` in new `BigQuery UI(BETA)`?  I didn't find anywhere in `UI`.
I'm trying to use my `UDFs` in new `Web UI` but I'm not able to find out the option.

Please let me know whether new `UI` will support `UDFs` or not?

Comment: if you are using [Standard SQL UDF](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions) - they are inline with your SQL and do not require any special/additional UI. If you use legacy sql  - ideally just [migrate to standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql) but if not - you also can write them inline with your SQL

Answer (score 0):

Mikhail's comment is accurate. We currently have no plans to support legacy SQL UDFs in the new BQ UI.

Instead we recommend [migrating to standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql) and using [standard SQL UDFs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions), which appear inline in the query text.